# why does "open file location" option not show up in some of the windows 10 apps?

Tags: windows-10, file-location

I recently updated windows 10 to latest version 1909 Nov. 2019 but I am encountering a problem.

As far as I can remember whenever I right clicked any app in start menu (not shortcut), "open file location" option popped up but since updating the machine, it looks like it shows up only for some selected apps like "firefox", or sys-admin tools like "command prompt" and others not for everything like "calculator", "word" or "excel".

However, by its feel it looks like a new update not any bug. So, is it really a update that disabled some apps for the option or any bug? 
I, however, tried following methods to solve this:-

1. Recreating the "IsShortcut" registry value in registry. https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/open-file-location-missing-right-click-shortcut-windows-7-vista/
2. Running shellexview software and checking shell extensions https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-slow-right-click-crashes-shell-extensions/

But all in vain. So how do I solve it (if it's a bug at all)? If not, then is there any way to get shown the "open file location" up upon right clicking or finding file location by any other method except manually surfing C drive?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you not just noticing that Stor/UWP apps don't have the option (which has always been the case). For example, **Notepad** has the option, but **Weather* does not.

Comment: @Keith Thanks for pointing out. Interestingly, I never noticed this novice thing!